# Usar libs como o jQuery influencia negativamente na performance/tempo de carregamento de uma página?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Digo pelo fato de ela usar muitos métodos... Isso influencia no carregamento da página?

Pois soube que o ranqueamento dos motores de buscas levam em conta o tempo de carregamento do site. Então, um sistema feito (bem feito) em "linguagens puras", sem frameworks, teria mais performance?

Answer (score 1):

O que mais influencia o carregamento da página é a requisição síncrona do arquivo. Esses fatores talvez também possam influenciar muito pouco:

- Interpretar o código;
- Executar o código.

Enquanto o código (sem o atributo "async", então síncrono) está no estado de interpretação e execução a página iria dormir, sem contar que o código, depois de executado, ainda fica dentro da memória amortecido até que você saia da aba/janela do navegador (okay, isso depende do navegador).

Mas no caso do jQuery, quando executado não faz nada na página HTML. Isso depende da forma como você utiliza ele. A dica é sempre esperar a página carregar para fazer as inicializações de requisições, eventos, etc.

```
$(_ => {
    /* statements */
})
```

O jQuery realmente não influencia o carregamento. Se você preferir que a página ainda carregue enquanto o jQuery executa, coloque o atributo "async" no script de inclusão, lembrando que isso pode prevenir que você use o jQuery por primeira rodada nos escopos dos outros códigos. De qualquer forma, você sabe que o que afeta mais o carregamento da página são requisições síncronas, diálogos e confirmações (talvez até iframe direto).

Para a última pergunta: "provavelmente sim", se estiver fazendo as coisas corretamente, evitando construir objetos locais, evitando construir funções aninhadas, há um monte de fatores que podem contribuir para a performance e podem ser facilmente achados por pesquisa. Lembrando: você terá que lidar com os problemas de navegador antigo, ou então alternativamente você pode criar sua própria API para fazer tarefas largas para cada coisa.